# Cannot remove telephone and region/province from billing information on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, billing-address

I am trying to remove the telephone and state/province field as a required field in my checkout.

I have already successfully removed it from the shipping section, and I tried to remove it the following way:

**1.) I have removed the class="required" and the * from the following files**

checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

Like I mentioned above the shipping one works fine but the billing not. 
When template hints are on it does not mention a different template.

**2.) I have copied the Abstract.php core class**

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php
```

And removed the validation there.

**3.) I have set the field in the database to not required.**

However in the billing section when I checkout, the telephone field and province field are still required and the "*" is also still coming up.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another extension where the billing section was created after editing it, it worked like it should.

I guess template path hints should also be looked at carefully :-)

That was the file

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/outsourceOnline/captcha/onepage_billing.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

if the * is still coming up you obviously edited the wrong phtml file, for starters turn on template paths and get the right phtml file to edit

Comment: Did that but it does not show any different .phtml file, it just shows onepage.phtml and no specific billing or shipping.phtml file

Comment: screenshot might help

Comment: screenshot of what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I know is late but in case others are here, for removing region/province, do edit the following:

- /checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
- /checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
- app/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Adress/Abstract.php
- /skin/frontend/default/(your skin)/js/opcheckout.js

billing.phtml: Comment out the following

```
<div class="field">
                        <div class="input-box"  style="display:none" readonly >
                            <select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" style="display:none" readonly  id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

shipping.phtml: Comment out the following (same codes as billing.phtml)

```
<div class="field">
                        <label for="shipping:region" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="shipping:region_id" name="shipping[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('shipping:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="shipping:region" name="shipping[region]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Abstract.php: Comment out the following

```
        if ($this->getCountryModel()->getRegionCollection()->getSize()
        && !Zend_Validate::is($this->getRegionId(), 'NotEmpty')
        && Mage::helper('directory')->isRegionRequired($this->getCountryId())
    ) {
        $this->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the state/province.'));
    }
```

opcheckout.js: Comment out the following.

1st part

```
if (window.billingRegionUpdater) {
                billingRegionUpdater.update();
            }
```

2nd part

```
if (window.shippingRegionUpdater) {
                shippingRegionUpdater.update();
            }
```

3rd part

```
 shippingRegionUpdater.update();
        $('shipping:region_id').value = $('billing:region_id').value;
        $('shipping:region').value = $('billing:region').value;
```

4th part

```
setRegionValue: function(){
    $('shipping:region').value = $('billing:region').value;
},
```

You should be fine by now.